# Durbin Watson test P value

Tags: python, stat

Is there anyway I could calculate the Durbin-Watson test P value in Python? In SAS I could do somthing like:

```
proc autoreg data=a;
   model y = time / dw=4 dwprob;
run;
```

The dwprob would give me the p value. Can I do something comparable in Python?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.stattools.durbin_watson.html